# Postgres tablespace size is bigger than database size

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

PostgreSQL tablespace size is bigger than database size. What is the problem about that?

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('ibidev'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2578 MB
(1 row)

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size('tbs_ibi_dat'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 47 GB
(1 row)
```

Using PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 3):

A tablespace can contain tables from more than one database.

The extra space must be from another database.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem: it was caused by `pgsql_tmp dir` in the `tbs_ibi_dat` tablespace. I ran a bad query with many sorting data so PostgreSQL stored that sorting data in that directory.